# C# New Expression in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I wrote a code and used LINQ for fun which shows Sum of even and odd numbers. My code is working well but i feel like i could do it much better than this

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bKlN.png) for image.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Func<int, int, IEnumerable<int>> NumberRange =
            (startPoint, endPoint) =>
            Enumerable
            .Range(Math.Min(startPoint, endPoint), Math.Abs(startPoint - endPoint) + 1);

        Func<double, double, bool> IsDivisible =
            (value, divisor) =>
                (value % divisor)
                .Equals(0);

        Action<IEnumerable<object>> DisplayItems =
            (data) =>
            {
                Console
                    .WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, data.Select(n => n)));
            };

        Func<bool, string> GetState =
            (key) =>
                key.Equals(true) ? "even" : "odd";

        var query =
            NumberRange(1, 20)
                .GroupBy(item => IsDivisible(item, 2))
                .Select(group => new
                {
                    Type = GetState(group.Key),
                    Sum = group.Sum()
                })
                .Select(group => new
                {
                    Output = string.Format("Sum of {0} numbers is {1}", group.Type, group.Sum)
                }
                .Output
                );

        DisplayItems(query);

        Console
            .Read();

    }
```

Is there any optimization for new expression ? Thanks.

Comment: I think simple loops (or simple utility functions) would be more readible than this. This makes me fell just *"look, I can write linq"*

Comment: int odds = 0; int evens = 0; foreach(var val in Enumerable.Range(1, 20)) if(val % 2 == 0) evens += val; else odds += val; Agreed with Eser, Linq can be dangerous in performance terms, use it wisely.

Comment: Instead of doing these funcs, put all this stuff into proper extension methods or something.

Comment: I tested with stopwatch Func<> is faster than predicate method. I don't know how. Thanks for you advice @Gusman but my aim is improve my LINQ skills.

Comment: Ok, that's fair enough, maybe you should improve your answer so the people know you are doing this to improve your skills. A good optimization is to use compiled expressions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @JimGarrison Stack Overflow has no such off-topic reason. What you mean is that the question is [off-topic because there is no specific question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it's simpler:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int startPoint = 0, endPoint = 20;

        List<int> data = new List<int>();
        int i = startPoint;
        while (i <= endPoint)
        {
            data.Add(i);
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Sum of even numbers is {0} \r\n", data.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Sum().ToString()));

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Sum of odd numbers is {0} \r\n", data.Where(x => x % 2 != 0).Sum().ToString()));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I thought .GroupBy is faster because you are checking twice numbers. It can be slow down speed.